# Equivalence of Functional dependency set

Tags: database-theory

Fd1 = {AB --> C, D --> E, E --> C}

Fd2 = { AB --> C, D --> E, AB --> E, E --> C}

are these two FD's are equivalent or not, i think they are. But in the answer it's shown as not equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot produce AB → E from dependencies in the first set.

To mathematically prove their (in)equivalence, you should build closures for both sets and compare the closures.

There are a few simple induction rules to build the a closure. Quoting [Wikipedia on Functional Dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency#Properties_and_axiomatization_of_functional_dependencies), the axioms are:

- **Reflexivity**: If Y is a subset of X, then X → Y
- **Augmentation**: If X → Y, then XZ → YZ
- **Transitivity**: If X → Y and Y → Z, then X → Z

with by a few rules that follow from them:

- **Union**: If X → Y and X → Z, then X → YZ
- **Decomposition**: If X → YZ, then X → Y and X → Z
- **Pseudotransitivity**: If X → Y and WY → Z, then WX → Z
- **Composition**: If X → Y and Z → W, then XZ → YW

Using these rules and axioms, one can build a closure for a FDS.

Omitting trivial dependencies (the ones where right side is included into left side), first set { AB → C *(1)*, D → E *(2)*, E → C *(3)* } gives:

```
AB → C                       (1)
ABD → CE, ABD → C, ABD → E   (composition 1+2, decomposition)
ABDE → CE, ABDE → C          (composition 1+2+3, decomposition)
ABE → C                      (composition 1+3)
D → E, D → C, D → CE         (2, transitivity 2+3, union)
DE → CE, DE → C              (composition 2+3, decomposition)
E → C                        (3)
```

And the second set { AB → C *(1)*, D → E *(2)*, E → C *(3)*, AB → E *(4)* } gives:

```
AB → C, AB → E, AB → CE      (1, 4, union 1+4)
ABD → CE, ABD → C, ABD → E   (composition 1+2, decomposition)
ABDE → CE, ABDE → C          (composition 1+2+3, decomposition)
ABE → C                      (composition 1+3)
D → E, D → C, D → CE         (2, transitivity 2+3, union)
DE → CE, DE → C              (composition 2+3, decomposition)
E → C                        (3)
```

The second closure has `AB → E, AB → CE`, which is not present in the first closure, therefore original sets are different.

Comment: That answered my question and pretty much everything else. Thanks.